# (Symfony 4 Forms) Passing non-entity query results to a form function

Tags: forms, symfony

I don't know how to tell my form type class to accept the choice_value function parameter for an incoming key/value array.

Here's what my form type buildForm function looks like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('tiers', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'  => $this->userSubscriptionTierRepository->getTiersSubscribedToByUser($this->userProvider->getCurrentUser()),
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => false,
            'attr'=> array('class'=>'custom-select'),
            'choice_value' => function (array $val /* this is wrong */) {
                return $val['tierNumber'];
            }
            ])
    ;
}
```

At the bottom, where 'choice_value' is, I don't know how to declare the function properly to accept the incoming value.

Here is what the choices "getTiersSubscribedToByUser" function looks like:

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 * @return array
 */
public function getTiersSubscribedToByUser(User $user) : array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');
    $qb->select('t.tierNumber, COUNT(t.tierNumber)')
        ->innerJoin('t.subscriptions', 'subscriptions', 'WITH', 'subscriptions.isCancelled != :true')
        ->where('subscriptions.subscriber = :user')
        ->groupBy('t.tierNumber')
        ->orderBy('t.tierNumber', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->setParameter('true', true);

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

And here is what the resultsof getTiersSubscribedToByUser look like:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "tierNumber" => 1
    1 => "2"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "tierNumber" => 2
    1 => "1"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "tierNumber" => 3
    1 => "1"
  ]
]
```

So I have to tell the form type class choice value to accept what looks like this:

```
1 => array:2 [▼
        "tierNumber" => 2
        1 => "1"
```

How do I do this?

It gives me the error:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Form\FeedFilterType::App\Form\{closure}() must be of the type array, integer given
```

Comment: Have you tried to dump() array $val? just remove the `array` part and put a dump() and an exit to see its value.

Comment: `If there are choice values that are not scalar or the stringified representation is not unique Symfony will use incrementing integers as values. When the form gets submitted the correct values with the correct types will be assigned to the model.`
https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices

Comment: JorgeeFG, I tried doing a dump and I got the number "1".  But that still doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Choice value is going to give you exactly what he is saying, the value of each choice. If you are sending `$val['tierNumber']` , according to your given array, you're going to get an integer is true, but it expects an array.

According to docs for `choice_value` :

> ```
> This can be a callable or a property path. If null is given, an incrementing integer is used as the value. If you pass a callable, it will receive one argument: the choice itself.
> ```

As you don't use EntityType you don't need to handle choice_value, because your choice is not an object:

> If you pass a callable, it will receive one argument: the choice
>   itself. When using the EntityType Field, the argument will be the
>   entity object for each choice or null in some cases, which you need to
>   handle:

```
'choice_value' => function (MyOptionEntity $entity = null) {
    return $entity ? $entity->getId() : '';
},
```

Did you try not using choice_value?

Documentation here:
https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-value

Comment: If I don't use choice_value I get the following error:  PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on, but it found type "integer" while trying to traverse path "name" at property "name".

Comment: yes, because if you got on your choice_value an object, you will can do object.name (property path) , but here you have no object, so you have to pass a callable to your choice_label in order to get the right data